# Need Help D-link DWP-157 USSD

Tags: ussd

I am new to linux OS.
I have connected d-link USB data card to my laptop and I can connect to internet with that using mobile broadband connection.
but how can I check my data balance ? I mean USSD Code.
I have tried both modem manager GUI and prepaid manager app.

In Modem Manager

[image]

See.. the modem is listed.

but in info tab

[image]

And when I try to run USSD code

[image]

Please help me. I have tried a lot of methods from askubuntu and other sites. no result.

I just only want to run ussd codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a command line application called "gammu". Open the terminal (press `Ctrl+Alt+t`) and type `sudo apt-get install gammu`. Type in the password when prompted(password will be invisible).
After installing gammu create the configuration file for gammu using the command   `gammu-detect > .gammurc`. Ignore any output in the terminal. This command will create a hidden configuration file in your home folder. Open your file browser (nautilus) and press `ctrl+h` to view hidden files. Check whether the `.gammurc` file is created.
Open the configuration file created and check for the devices detected by gammu. The devices listed as ttyUSB0 to ttyUSB3 belong to the D-Link modem.
Using gammu you can send ussd only if you are not presently connected to internet. So to send ussd disconnect from the internet connection.
Now to send a ussd type the following command in "terminal" : `gammu getussd "USSD_CODE"`. For example `gammu getussd *125#`. Then wait for some time and you will get the reply for the ussd(time depends on the network provider. Took 2 min for me!).
If proper reply is not getting, add the device number along with the above command ie, `gammu 1 getussd *125#` or `gammu 2 getussd *125#` etc.
'gammu 1 getussd *125#' worked for me in Ubuntu 14.04 with D-Link DWP-156. It should work with DWP-157 as well. Good luck on that :)
 Explore the manual pages of gammu by issuing the command `man gammu` in the terminal.